# Form submitting with Angular

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, forms

I used the following codes for creating a form submit with angular $http.

HTML (in the controller `div`):

```
<input type="text" name="job" ng-model="item.job">
<button type="submit" ng-click="post()">Add</button>
```

JS (in the app controller):

```
$scope.post = function() {
            $scope.item.done = "";
            $http.post("data/todo.json", $scope.item)
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log("OK");                  
                })
                .error(function () {
                    console.log("Sorry");                   
                });
        };
```

After run, it seems everything is OK and success message comes to console, but the `todo.json` file doesn't change!

Any Idea?

Comment: why it is supposed to change?

Comment: By form submit, I add an item to json array! where does it go?!

Comment: your url is pointing to json file you cant edit it with an post request

Answer (score 0):

You need server side implementation in order to handle your post requests. You can use node.js, mvc.net, java etc.

Comment: But why does it return the success status?

Comment: Probably the request is ok because your current server side code handles the request. But you cant change json file by simple post. You need code that will change the file